# A word for sucking venom off a wound

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for sucking venom off a wound?

I remember encountering a semi-scientific word for the process. It is something that can be used like this:

> She performed (insert word) on his snake-bite to save him, but not only was it ineffective, she also swallowed some, and they're both
>   dead now.

Comment: http://uk.businessinsider.com/how-to-survive-snake-bite-venomous-venom-attack-2018-5?IR=T (good video)

Comment: suck, suction, extraction, bleeding:  there has never been a formal word in AmE.  @Kris is closest and is what i was taught in the good ole B.S.A.!

Comment: The word is ***foolish***

Answer (score 1):

The old (folk) technique no longer recommended is called the **[Cut-and-Suck](https://www.outdoorlife.com/blogs/survivalist/dont-cut-and-suck-snakebite%E2%80%94do-instead-if-youre-bitten-venomous-snake)** method.

---

**EDIT**
*See also:*

Blackman (1992), *[Venomous Snakebite](http://www.jabfm.org/content/5/4/399.full.pdf),* JABFP **5**:4 p.402 (pdf;580kB)

> Commercial suction devices are readily available (Sawyer Ex-traction Pump™) and should replace the old **method of incision and suction**.  (emphasis mine)

*and*

> [**Incision and Suction** (or "**Cut and Suck**")](http://www.selfcare.info/hc1/adult/BitesStings/SnakeBite.htm): Do NOT perform incision and suction. The majority of experts recommend against this. In addition, an incision performed by a hurried, nervous, and inexperienced individual may result in damage to an artery, nerve, or tendon. <sub>Copyright © 2000-2003 David Thompson, M.D. FACEP; ©2017 Self Care Decisions.</sub>

Comment: Yeah, but that isn't really one word. What i'm looking for is a little sciency.

Comment: @physkets it doesn’t sound sciency but it’s used in peer reviewed papers : http://www.bioone.org/doi/abs/10.2993/0278-0771(2005)25%5B129:ISBROT%5D2.0.CO%3B2#/doi/abs/10.2993/0278-0771(2005)25%5B129:ISBROT%5D2.0.CO%3B2

Answer (score 0):

Is **"suction"** the word that you are looking for? It seems the appropriate word to use in your example, and I can't find any synonyms that are equally effective. Applying "negative pressure" is more than one word.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/suction

Answer (score 0):

It just seems to be called *extraction* in [this article](https://www.offgridweb.com/preparation/debunked-sucking-venom-from-a-snakebite/). I couldn't find any other more technical terms apart from "sucking the venom out":

> DEBUNKED: SUCKING VENOM FROM A SNAKEBITE
>   [...] Many medical authorities, including the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention, agree that almost no venom will be removed by extraction and that extraction kits are essentially useless. [...]

Note: of course, you shouldn't be doing that, as it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you write the title of the article, and maybe include a quote from it?

Comment: +1 for "sucking venom ***out***…" though

Comment: Maybe I should also add a health warning that you might want to be careful with a web search on those terms unless you have 'safe search' enabled...

Comment: Extraction also refers to devices that allege to remove venom not just removal by mouth. (These devices probably aren’t effective either with removing venom but that’s another question )